# Trouble understanding bluetooth input and output android

Tags: android, bluetooth

The following code is taken from [here](http://project-greengiant.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Blog/Android%20Arduino%20Bluetooth/Android/AndroidArduinoBluetooth/src/Android/Arduino/Bluetooth/BluetoothTest.java)

Can someone please explain in deep how this works?

What is this handler and what does it do?

How is the while condition implemented?.

How does the loop proceed?

I have very crude understanding how the code works , it would very much benefit me if you could help me out. Thank you.

```
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {                
           while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
           {
                try 
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();                        
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        myLabel.setText(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
           }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
}

void sendData() throws IOException
{
    String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
    msg += "\n";
    mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    myLabel.setText("Data Sent");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to know what a thread is, or I can clarify it.
The code you provide, as you should know, is defining your workerThread. All that is written in the run method will be run in another thread, once you call start() on that thread. All the the variables defined before the run method are define in the main thread. So is the Handler.

A Handler aims at linking 2 threads. You define it in one thread (here the main thread before the run method), and you use it in another thread (in the run method) to execute some action in thread where it was defined. SO in your code, you call

```
handler.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    myLabel.setText(data);
                                }
                            });
```

from the workerThread, so

```
myLabel.setText(data);
```

will be executed from the main thread (the thread where was instantiated your handler).

Why is it doing so? Because .setText() can't be called from another thread than the main thread as it is drawing something.

The while loop checks that the thread hasn't been interrupted (by Android or something else) and that your boolean stopWorker hasn't been modified, so that there was no Exception thrown while reading from your inputStream

try{}catch(){} is just a way to manage exceptions.

.available() method gives you the number of bytes you can read from the inpuStream by calling the .read() method. If there are some available bytes (so if you phone received something from the connected device), then it reads it.

To read method works this way: you pas a byte array as argument, and it will get the available bytes from the input stream and put them into the byte array.

Then it processes the bytes received...

But for me it's not an efficient solution, because the thread will loop very fast, whereas .read() is a blocking method, so all the part checking that checking that there are some bytes available is useless, and even inefficient. .read() would make the thread sleep until new bytes are available, and thus releasing resources. Maybe there is another reason why the code is doing so but I don't see it.

Hope that's clear.